# Matplotlib : Consistent Y-Axis across 4 Separate Line Plots

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have 4 dictionaries which are dictionaries of lists.

This is being used to plot the volume per month of various entities as multiple line plots.

Each dictionary key has the value as a list of 12 values each representing the volume of the corresponding month

I have 4 dictionaries : d1, d2, d3 and d4.

Sample value of a dictionary element - `[239, 138, 271, 175, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 24, 62]`

How do I ensure the same Y-Axis value (sharey ?) across all 4 ?

```
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=600)
plt.margins(0.075)
labels = []
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.title('Monthwise Volume per Queue', {'family' : 'Arial Black',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22})
for i in d2:
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], d2[i])
    labels.append(i)
    months = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
plt.xticks(range(len(months)), months, rotation='vertical')
plt.legend(labels, ncol=1, loc='upper left', 
           bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.1], 
           columnspacing=1.0, labelspacing=0.0,
           handletextpad=0.0, handlelength=1.5,
           fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using yticks property as in:

```
plt.yticks(sharey) #where sharey is your list of values
```